# Computer only starts on Last known good configuration

Tags: windows-server-2003, troubleshooting

My computer restarts everytime the login dialog is about to appear.
It only loads fine on 'Last known good configuration' option

What steps should I follow to debug this issue?

OS: Windows  Server 2003

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debugging is going to be very difficult but if it boots to the last known good configuration then obviously the problem is connected to whatever changed since the last successful boot. So, what changed?

Comment: I don't remember. I've been working on last known good configuration for weeks.

Comment: Something is odd. If you boot from last known good and log on, when the machine is shut down that should be saved as the current configuration, meaning you should be able to boot normally from then on. If that's not happening for you it might be safest to restore from backup or do a full reinstall, because there's no telling what else might be broken.

Comment: True that but there was probably some program corrupting the state every time. I uninstalled all the crappy software I wasn't using and the problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a BSOD, the your first step is to get the dump from the C:\Windows\Minidump directory (usually by booting to Safemode/Command Prompt, WinPE, or a Recovery session) and running that through a dump reader (dumpchk and the Windows Debugging Tools are a good start, and free from MS [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315263)).

Another option is simply to go to your latest working backup. But this of course depends on what's on the server and how good your backups are.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to restart your computer and press f8 when it starts, load the last normal settings,it will fix the problems caused by the latest install of software or updates of hardware.